# iPad Retina development

Tags: ios, ipad, xcode4.3, ios5.1, retina-display

If I **currently** have an ipad app that **supports** `ios 5.0` how do I go about *merging* my graphics to fit flush on an `ipad 3` & `ios 5.1`?

I have been *looking* through [these apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/checklist/), but I'm not finding anything about `5.0` to `5.1` *conversion*. Any **tips**?

I just want to be able to use *high resolution* graphics. My current graphics are all *pixelated* on the `5.1` sim.

*Thanks!*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to update your apps with @2x versions of your iPad graphic assets, at a minimum. So for MyImage.png you'll need a double-size version named MyImage@2x.png. If you have a universal app, and say, the following 3 images for iPhone, iPhone Retina, and iPad:

- MyImage.png
- MyImage@2x.png
- MyImage~ipad.png

you would need to create MyImage@2x~ipad.png.

I think I have that right.... Could be that in this case the iPhone images would have ~iphone in their names too, but I don't think that is a requirement. (It's allowed, but not a requirement, I believe.)

Comment: @sch are you referring to the dimensions or the dpi?

Comment: The new file should be called:  MyImage@2x~ipad.png.
"If you combine the at2x string with other modifiers, the at2x string should come before any device modifiers but after all other modifiers, such as launch orientation or URL scheme modifiers."  From: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/ImageSoundResources/ImageSoundResources.html
(I had to replace with at2x in order to be able to get past a StackOverflow restriction)

Comment: in fact, I discovered today that ~iphone images will not load under certain circunstances.